# count the odd numbers in a specified range

Tags: java

How do I a get the counter to count the odd number under 100 in this program?

```
public class checkpassfail {

public static void main(String[] args) {
int sum =0;
double avr;
int lower = 1;
int uper = 100;
int num=lower;
 int counter =0;
 while( num <= uper){
     sum= sum+(num+=3);
     counter+=3;
     }


System.out.println("the sum of these nubers is\t" +sum);
System.out.println(counter);
double s =(double)sum;
avr =s/counter;
System.out.println("the average of these nubers is \t"+avr);
}
```

Comment: Why do you add `3` if the odd number is every second one?

Comment: `long count = IntStream.rangeClosed(lower, uper).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).count();`

Comment: I do believe that the task description and the representing code have nothing in common besides the upper limit 100.

Comment: Half of the integers in any range will be odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you actually want to do?

If I'm not wrong you want to find odd numbers in between **lower_bound** and **upper_bound**.

```
int lower_bound = 0, upper_bound = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(lower_bound < upper_bound)
{
    if(lower_bound % 2 == 1)
         odds.add(lower_bound);
    lower_bound++;
}

// Number of odd numbers found
int numberOfOddsFound = odds.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Using the `for-loop`, you calculate these aggregated values with:

```
final int lower = 1;           // Lower bound
final int upper = 100;         // Upper bound

int sum = 0;                   // Default sum
int count = 0;                 // Default count
double average = Double.NaN;   // Default average

int i = lower;                 // Init the "runnig" variable
while (i <= upper){            // Until the upper bound is reached, do:
     sum += i;                 // Add the number to the overall sum
     count++;                  // One more number has been used - count it
     i += 2;                   // Add 2 since you mind odd values only
}

average = sum / count;         // Calculate the average
                               // And enjoy the results below      

System.out.println("Count: " + count);
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

There also other ways of using the formulas to calculate these characteristics of a regular sequence of numbers or with Stream-API using `IntStream.range(..)` which allows calculating the aggregation values directly. However, in the beginning, stick with the `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do all of this I guess. If you already know the highest value and the lowest value, and you want to count how many odd numbers between that range, you can code it like below.

```
int odd_count = (upper + 1) / 2 - lower / 2;

public class checkpassfail {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int lower = 1;
int upper = 100;

int odd_count = (upper + 1) / 2 - lower / 2;
System.out.println("Odd numbers count = "odd_count);
}
}
```

This will print Odd numbers count = 50.